# How to add middleware to get serverSideProps in next js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I need to add some node js middleware on this function

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

  console.log('coo',cookieParser(ctx.req.headers.cookie));
  console.log('headers', ctx.req.headers.cookie);
 const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/publics')
 const data = await res.json()
 const theData = data[ctx.query.id - 1]

 return {
    props: {data: theData}, 
  }
}
```

I need to use the cookie parser middleware, Is there anyway to add middleware here and if not, How can i get the info from the cookie

Comment: You already have access to `req.cookies` in `getServerSideProps` by default.

Comment: Hey @MrBadonkadonkoi, did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nookies](https://github.com/maticzav/nookies), for example:

```
import nookies from 'nookies'

export default function Me() {
  return <div>My profile</div>
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  // Parse
  const cookies = nookies.get(ctx)

  // Set
  nookies.set(ctx, 'fromGetInitialProps', 'value', {
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    path: '/',
  })

  // Destroy
  // nookies.destroy(ctx, 'cookieName')

  return { cookies }
}
```